# Getting the activities of followed objects

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, collections

I'm using the acts_as_follower gem in addition to the polymorphic activity tracking I've setup between my user and artist models. I'm now trying to display all of the activities of followed artists in the user's show view. At first I thought I could simply create an instance variable of artists by using the gem's [all_follows](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower#acts_as_follower-methods) method:

```
current_user.all_follows
=> #<ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation [#<Follow id: 8, followable_id: 1, followable_type: "Artist", follower_id: 1, follower_type: "User", blocked: false, created_at: "2016-02-29 12:56:31", updated_at: "2016-02-29 12:56:31">]>
```

As you can see it returns the `Follow` object(s) vs. the `Artist` objects I'm looking to retrieve. I had an alternative idea by performing a sql query on the `Activity` class:

```
Activity.where(followable_id: current_user.follows.pluck(&:id))
```

This gives me the error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: activities.followable_id: SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."followable_id" IN (8, 1, 'Artist', 1, 'User', 'f', '2016-02-29 12:56:31.974244', '2016-02-29 12:56:31.974244')
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: activities.followable_id: SELECT "activities".* FROM "activities" WHERE "activities"."followable_id" IN (8, 1, 'Artist', 1, 'User', 'f', '2016-02-29 12:56:31.974244', '2016-02-29 12:56:31.974244')
```

What would be the best way to retrieve these records?

```
class Artist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :activities, as: :owner, dependent: :destroy
  acts_as_followable
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_follower
end

class Activity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
end

class Follow < ActiveRecord::Base
  extend ActsAsFollower::FollowerLib
  extend ActsAsFollower::FollowScopes

  belongs_to :followable, polymorphic: true
  belongs_to :follower, polymorphic: true
end
```

---

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @artist_activity = Activity.where(followable_id: current_user.follows.pluck(&:id))
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post your schema..

Comment: There is no column named `followable_id` in `Activity` table so you can't do this, and there is no relation between `activity` and `follows` model

Comment: What's your environment (ruby and rails version)? I'm going to replicate your setup so I can work this with you.

Comment: Ruby: ruby 2.0.0, Rails: 4.2.0. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Curious how it's going

Comment: Hey thanks for checking in. I managed to solve it using the answer I wrote below. It won't let me mark it as correct until tomorrow. Let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to work for me:

```
Activity
  .where(owner_type: 'Artist')
  .where(:owner_id => current_user.all_follows
                          .where(followable_type: 'Artist')
                          .map(&:followable)
                          .map{|artist| artist.id}
   )
```

It might be better as:

```
Activity.where(owner: current_user.all_follows
                                  .where(followable_type: 'Artist')
                                  .map(&:followable)
        )
```

But I haven't tested it.

So, this bit:

```
  current_user.all_follows
              .where(followable_type: 'Artist')
              .map(&:followable)
```

Creates an array of objects by virtue of the `.map(&followable)` bit. In this case, it happens to be an array of Artist objects because of `.where(followable_type: 'Artist')`.

`Activity` stipulates that the owner is polymorphic. So, AR is smart enough, when passing in an array of objects, to match on both the `owner_type` and the `owner_id` - so you don't have to be as explicit as I was in the first example.

With ordering:

```
Activity.where(owner: current_user.all_follows
                                  .where(followable_type: 'Artist')
                                  .map(&:followable)
        ).order(created_at: :desc)
```

Comment: Thanks. Being that I'm gather potentially a multitude of artists what does `@artist` represent?

Comment: Sorry, I assumed you wanted the activities for a **specific** artist. Will update answer.

Comment: Yeah. Basically I want to gather the activities of all the artists an individual follows.

Comment: I'm getting an error when I introduce `joins(:artist)`

Comment: `ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Association named 'artist' was not found on Follow; perhaps you misspelled it?`

Comment: This looks like it works. If you'd like to explain why I'm all ears.

Comment: Just noticed there's one additional fix needed for your answer. Right now you're querying `user` where it should be `current_user`. Otherwise it'll raise an *undefined variable* error. Also may be a good idea to order it in descending order.

Comment: Thanks, I just took a look at the update. Would you say that your solution is more performant?

Comment: Well, functionally, yes - in that your answer potentially gives you inappropriate Activities (as noted). From a speed or database load (demand) perspective - I don't know. But, I would speculate that they are somewhere in the same ballpark. You'd have to do a performance test to know for sure.

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna mark yours as correct. Appreciate your help to get  this solved.

Answer (score 0):

Was originally on the right track but should've queried by the owner (i.e. artist) and from there gather and pluck the their `followable_id`:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def show    
    @artist_activity = Activity.order("created_at desc").where(owner: current_user.all_follows.pluck(&:followable_id))
  end
end
```

Comment: Will your system ever evolve to a place where a user can follow something other than an artist?

Comment: Yeah. Possibly other users down the road. Why do you ask?

Comment: First, let me say I like what you did and I'm learning a lot myself. So, this is entirely in that spirit. Now, I could be mistaken, but let's say you have: an Artist with id: 1, an Artist with id: 2, a Group with id: 1, and a Group with id: 2. All have activity. current_user follows Artist with id:1 and Group with id: 2. I think your method is going to pick up **all activity** for **all artists** and **all groups** including those artists and groups that the current user doesn't follow. But, I could be wrong.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Being that the activities are setup through polymorphic associations I may be able to go by the `followable_id` and `follower_type`. That way it could decipher between an Artist or Group. Does that make sense?

Comment: I just updated my answer. I haven't tested it, but I think this will ensure the polymorphic joins work correctly (I think even if you omit the `.where(followable_type: 'Artist')` bit).